# Pywebio Button to redirect to another url

Tags: python, flask, redirect, button

I want a button in my pywebio,which on click will redirect to localhost//:4200 . My pywebio runs in localhost:8080, i want to redirect it to a page in port:4200

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what didn't work about those attempts. Please [edit] your post to contain this information.

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple, not much documentation for on click. But it looks for a function

```
import webbrowser

def my_function():
    webbrowser.open_new_tab('Your_URL')
    
put_button("Button", onclick=lambda: my_function())
```